# I'm trying to rebuild the indexes on a Progress database after a huge binary load, getting this error

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

Just imported 655 tables via binary load using a batch script to a newly created database on a 650gb hard drive.

Idxbuild is running with threads, the maximum number of threads is 1. (13942)
TMB value is 8, TM value is 8, SG value is 48, packing factor is 100. (16141)
Temporary sort file at: C:\Progress\OpenEdge\bin will use the available disk spa
ce. (11443)
SYSTEM ERROR: Unable to extend database within area Schema Area. (8897)

I can't find any solution to this in the documentation.

Tom Bascom -- I know you know a solution to this.

Thank You community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Progress?

As Tim says, that's a very odd place for your temp files.  How did that happen?  My guess is that your working directory is %DLC%\bin.

You're extending the schema area?  Why?  Did you forget to move all of your data, indexes and LOBs to type 2 storage?

By eliminating all of the AREA information from the structure file you put everything in the schema area.

You probably also did not create a structure file with multiple extents and so forth?  Thus there is just the single initial extent.

It also seems likely that you did not enable large files.  Which means that once that extent hits 2GB it cannot grow.

So the quick and easy solution is probably:

```
proutil dbName -C enablelargefiles
```

Note: this is a terrible way to set setup a database -- don't do it for a real system.  But, as I understand it, you are just trying to do a one-time load of this data so that you can export it as CSV data.

Comment: I created the binary dump files from a version 10.1b database. I was also able to get .df files. I had to create 5 different .df files because there are so many tables. I'm not trying to extend the Schema area I'm just trying to rebuild the indexes after binary loading everything. Here's how I did it -- I couldn't get a -dumplist because the actual dump utility was unavailable to me in the proprietary copy of 10.1b I was initially working with. So I found a batch script that created a .bd file fore each table.

Comment: I got a quote back from Progress software for the 10.1b developers seat and it was way out of our budget. We were willing to spend $500.00 on the seat but they quoted us $2500. SO I decided I would load these binary dumps into an evaluation version 11.0. Bear in mind my only intention here is to get the data to text. So When I tried to import the .df files to my newly minted version 11 database it barked because I didn't have any of the same areas (many) so I used notepad++ to remove the thousands of references to areas in .df and the tables were all created using the database Admin utility.

Comment: Then I was able to create a batch script using some regex that wrapped every path, in this directory of 655 .bd files, with the proutil -C load command. The script was successful and it successfully imported each of the 655 tables. The other day when I was testing this I was able to import 1 table, rebuild the index for that one table, and export this data to text. Now that I've got all 655 tables -- it fails on the index rebuild -- saying that it can't extend the database.

Comment: Now that we have a bit of context it's a bit easier to answer ;)

Comment: On the license front -- that sounds like a full blown development license.  For your purposes a "query" license would have probably been adequate.  Or a "4gl compiler" license.

Comment: Thank You so much Tom -- I owe you a beer! Or some delicious fresh juice if that's not your thing. I was able to get the data. Here's what I did. I deleted the database -- then recreated it. I then enabled large files on the new database AND added a variable length extent of 4GB. Then I re-imported the edited structure files and the binary dumps. After that I was able to successfully rebuild all 3500 indexes. Then I ran some nifty code I found on progresstalk to dump every table to CSV.

Answer (score 1):

From the KB:

> This situation arises when the database Storage Area is either:
>
> a.)  composed entirely of fixed-length extents and the last extent has
>   become filled up, b.)  a variable length extent needs to exceed the
>   2Gig file size limit to accommodate writes and LargeFiles have not
>   been enabled, or c.)  when the user hits their ulimit as defined in
>   their .profile (UNIX) or disk quota limit (Windows)
>
> In any of the above cases, the PROGRESS run is aborted and recovery
>   must be run.

---

Also:

> More extents for the database to grow must be made avaialable. The
>   prostrct utility must be used to add additional space. In future, the
>   highwater mark of the last extent in an area can be monitored to
>   forewarn of this occurrence. Once this is done, restart the database
>   and allow crash recovery to take place.

and

> References to Written DocumentationReferences to
>   ProgressManuals:Database Administration Guide and Reference - Chapter
>   9 "Maintaining the Database Structure"

---

Also, why are you pointing your temp space for sorting at the progress bin directory? Point it at an empty temp directory instead.

Use the Temporary Directory (-T) startup parameter to identify or redirect temporary files created by the PROUTIL utility to a specified directory when sorting and handling space issues.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers -- I have the Database Administration guide it's been instrumental for me. I'm not sure when, why, or how my system was instructed to create temp files @ C:\Progress\OpenEdge\bin.. how can I change that?

Comment: If you're willing to spend some $, either Tom or I could provide the needed services to get the data loaded and then dumped back out again.

Comment: Tim -- thank you so much for your help. If we do need any further help with this I will contact you for consulting. I was able to get all the tables to CSV -- read comments below.